# Overlayer behaving as a Baselayer

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, mapping, gis

The control layers has 4 Overlayers: layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4. I want these overlayers to behave as a Baselayer. That means that one of the layer is checked the other ones are automatically unchecked. When checked layer1 for instance, I want to remove from the map layer2, layer3 and layer4 and their legend as well. The code bellow is showing that, however layer2, layer3, and layer4 are removed from the map only when I ZOOM IN and ZOOM OUT. And I want to wipe out or remove the layers right when checkbox is checked. Any hint on how I can achieve that?

```
layer1.on('loading', function () {
    $('#layer1')[0].textContent = 'myVar'
    $('#legend-layer1')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: show')
    $('#legend-layer2')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden')
    $('#legend-layer3')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden')
    $('#legend-layer4')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: hidden')
    if (map.hasLayer(layer2) || map.hasLayer(layer3)|| map.hasLayer(layer4)) {
        map.removeLayer(layer2)
        map.removeLayer(layer3)
        map.removeLayer(layer4)       
    };


});
```

Comment: Why are you using those layers as overlays in a `L.Control.Layers` instead of baselayers, in the first place?

Comment: @IvanSanchez, although the layers are global information, I need to have a global map as OpenStreetMap behind the layer to see the information  geographic limits. Any hint to that?